# Laravel 5 Throw an exception: BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5, and I'm a bit new to this framework. I searched a lot for the problem, but in return I got nothing related.

So, I have two models:
Article and Tag.

In Article Model I have a method like this:

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Tag");
}
```

And in my Tag Model I have a method like this:

```
public function articles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Article");
}
```

Now the thing is that when I'm testing this in tinker like this:

```
$article->tags()->attach(1);
```

It gives me the following Exception:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()'

But when I'm calling it like this:

```
$tag->articles()->attach(1);
```

It totally works like a charm and It doesn't throw any kind of Exception whatsoever.

I'm actually learning this stuff from Laracast and my Classes and methods and files are kind of like this:
[BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::belongToMany()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624946/badmethodcallexception-with-message-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-databas)

Except I think I don't have a typo problem.

Comment: This is my tinker screenshot everyone:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/HCNP2.png

Answer (score 2):

Well, I got the answer on my own & just share it for others.

The code doesn't have any problem.

I should've just restarted the Tinker. It was a Tinker problem.